# Conditionally select from one table or another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, case

I have two tables

```
TableA Column1, Column2,Column3, Column4
TableB Column1, Column2,Column3, Column4
```

Query to modify:

```
Select Column2,Column3, Column4
From TableA
```

How would I modify the above query to select Column3 from TableB if the value of TableA.Column2 exists in TableB? It would also have to be the max value of TableB.Column1.

```
TableA
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1        A      zebra     apple
2        C      lion      orange
3        R      giraffe   banana

TableB
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1       Q       snail     rock
2       C       frog      stone
3       Z       giraffe   tree
4       C       walrus    limb

Result
Column2          Column3   Column4
A                zebra     apple
C                walrus    orange
R                giraffe   banana
```

It might be something like:

```
   Select TableA.Column2,Case When Exists(Select TableB.Column3 From Table3 
   Where        Table2.Column = TableB.Column2 ) Then Select Table2.Column3 Where   [Table2.Column1 is  max value], Column4
   From TableA
```

Comment: A combination of a case construct and joining tables should do the trick.  It appears that you already know about the case construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this below:

```
select
    a.column2
    , case when b.column2 is not null then max(b.column3) else a.column3 end
    , a.column4
from
    tableA a
    left join tableB b
        on a.column2 = b.column2
group by
    a.column2
    , a.column3
    , a.column4
    , b.column2
```

If this is a homework assignment, as the question seems, please study the code to understand why and how and it works.

Comment: No, it is not a homework assignment. It is part of a much larger query with many joins. I was just trying to focus on one part of it. I understand it but will have to see if I can integrate it into the larger query. The group by might be difficult work in.

Comment: ah, in that case, you're welcome.  And thanks for simplifying the problem. :)

Comment: I'm still working on it. So far I'm only getting one row. That's without the group by. It probably has to do with another part of the long query. Is the group by necessary? Can you explain why? Thanks

Comment: Okay. I got it working except for one thing. I don't need max(b.column3). I need b.column3 where max(b.column1).

Comment: I'm not sure if I can get the max in a nested case, or if I need to do that in the join. I'm trying it both ways. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The reason for the group by is: Since your base table (table a) matches two rows in table B, and you only want the row from table B that is highest alphabetically, you have to have some mechanism to tell the query engine which row to pick.  The Group By causes the engine to only select the unique values across the four columns I named.  Then, in the Select clause, I use the max() function to grab the highest value of column3 that is found in each "group". For "A" and "R", there is only 1, so it picks each of those.  For "C", there are 2, so it picks "walrus" because "walrus" > "frog".

Comment: If the group by complicates things, another approach you might try is to use a table variable or Common Table Expression.  Then you can just reference what you selected as if it were itself a table.

Comment: Thanks. It would really need to choose the highest value from column1. That would be 4 > 2. I'll be working on it more later today and tomorrow. I've had and will have interruptions.

Comment: I got it using CTE. Thanks. That was a big help.